# How to write a Linq query to pick the last max number in the given strings ?

Tags: sql-server, string, linq, linq-to-sql

I have these strings in my column in my database. I am basically generating slug and don't want to duplicate any of the string. The strings can be in any order. 
How can I pick up the largest number in these strings which are there at the last efficiently using linq?

Example 1:

```
slug 

hhhh
hhhh-2 
hhhh-2-3
hhhh-4
hhhh-5
hhhh-2-4
```

The largest number above is 5.

Example 2:

```
slug 

hhhh
hhhh-2 
hhhh-2-3
hhhh-4
hhhh-2-4
```

The largest number above is 4.

Comment: Do you know the length of the `hhhh` string beforehand?

Comment: No it could be anything about-us or news-and-events or about-us-2 anything

Comment: have a look at this article which might give you a start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397940.aspx

Comment: is the string always in the order word-characters-digits ? Do you know how many digit groups you could get or is that not determined? I wonder if some regex solution would help here at all ?

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way that you will be able to do this *efficiently* without an appropriate database schema.

If you need to be able to query for this maximum number at all times you should create a table with "slug" and "max num" columns and update the "max num" whenever you have to.

However, it might be worthwhile to review *why* you want to do this. For example, if you want to safeguard against double usage *but actual collisions are expected to be rare* then you don't really *need* it to be efficient.